# Why the function returns integer while I expect to have a character vector?

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to make a function that will search for multicollinearity inside the given dataframe and return me (if any), the list of columns that has this feature like that: `[1] "V1" "V2" "V4" "V3"`

My not-so-fancy function below does that

```
multicol_test <- function(d){
  # Create an empty dataframe to store the results
  result_df <- data.frame()
  # Loop through each column
  for (i in 1:(ncol(d) - 1)) {
    for (j in (i + 1):ncol(d)) {
      # Compare columns (example: calculate mean difference)
      result <- cor(d[, i], d[, j])
      
      # Append the result to the result dataframe
      result_df <- rbind(result_df, 
                         data.frame(Column1 = names(d)[i], 
                                    Column2 = names(d)[j], 
                                    Result = result))  
    }
  }
  
  # Print the result dataframe
  result_df$Result <- abs(result_df$Result)
  # result_df$new <- result_df$Result
  result_df$sig <- as.character(result_df$Result)
  res <- result_df[result_df$Result==1,]
  res <- result_df[substr(result_df$sig, 1, 1) == "1", ]
  unique_values <- unique(c(res$Column1, res$Column2))
  if(length(unique_values)==0){
    return("There is no collinearity in the data")
  }else{
    return(unique_values)
  }
}
```

however the automatic verifier on site where I submit my solution tells me something like:

```
Failed. Runtime error

Error:
Error: The function should return a string, you have returned:

1 2 3

integer
Execution halted
```

What can be the source of a problem?

For this test df, for example the right answer is the one from above: `[1] "V1" "V2" "V4" "V3"`:

```
test_data <- as.data.frame(list(V1 = c(14, 9, 15, 15, 17), 
                                V2 = c(-9, 1, -4, -2, -7), 
                                V3 = c(13, 3, 8, 6, 11), 
                                V4 = c(9, 4, 10, 10, 12)))
```

Comment: Hi Lara! You will probably get better, faster help if you make this question reproducible. Good luck!

Comment: Your code and example worked for me in base R.